# Combine array of objects inner array based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

say I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
data = [
        {title: "Alpha", content: [{ // 1 item }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ // 10 items }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ // 12 items }]}, 
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ // 8 items }]} 
       ]
```

I'd like to figure out a reduce function that would return the following structure:

```
data = [
        {title: "Alpha", content: [{ // 1 item }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ // 30 items }]}
       ]
```

I've tried looking at some answers where reduce is used based on title but it did not return the new structure with the accumulated content array such as:

```
data = data.reduce((x, e) => {
          x.push(
            Object.assign(
              {},
              e,
              messages.find((x) => x.title == e.title)
            )
          )
          return x
        }, [])
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help -

```js
var data = [{
    title: "Alpha",
    content: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    title: "Beta",
    content: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  },
  {
    title: "Beta",
    content: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  },
  {
    title: "Beta",
    content: [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  }
]

data = data.reduce((array, item) => {
  const existingItem = array.find(innerItem => innerItem.title === item.title);
  if (!!existingItem) {
    existingItem.content = [...existingItem.content, ...item.content];
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
  return array;
}, []);


console.log(data);
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I want. When trying it out I get a `can't read content of undefined` error. To clarify the data structure content would be an array of objects (not numbers, I know I didnt make that clear) ... would that change your answer at all ?

Comment: Ideally array of anything should work here, can you check if you have any differences between this answer and your code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `.find`, which has to search the entire array every iteration.

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an object map to collect dupes, [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to unwrap object to array.  [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to feed as push arguments.

```js
data = [
        {title: "Alpha", content: [{ 1:1 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{2:2 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ 3:3}]}, 
        {title: "Beta", content: [{4:4}] }
       ]
console.log(
Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{title,content})=>{
  acc[title] ? 
    acc[title].content.push(...content) :
    acc[title] = { title, content }
  return acc
},{})
))
```

If IE compatible is needed, there is a polyfill on the above linked documentation.  This will also work:

```js
data = [
        {title: "Alpha", content: [{ 1:1 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{2:2 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ 3:3}]}, 
        {title: "Beta", content: [{4:4}] }
       ]
function values(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).map(k=>obj[k])
}
console.log(
values(data.reduce((acc,x)=>{
  acc[x.title] = acc[x.title] || {title: x.title, content: []}
  acc[x.title].content = acc[x.title].content.concat(x.content)
  return acc
},{})
))
```

Comment: Whilst this answer gives the correct answer, we need to keep in mind that `Object.values` is currently not supported in IE :)

Comment: The linked article already has a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values  which is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I made small changes from @user120242 code.

```js
data = [
        {title: "Alpha", content: [{ 1:1 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{2:2 }]},
        {title: "Beta", content: [{ 3:3}]}, 
        {title: "Beta", content: [{4:4}] }
       ]
let acc={};
data.forEach((x)=>{
  acc[x.title] = acc[x.title] || {title: x.title, content: []}
  acc[x.title].content = acc[x.title].content.concat(x.content)
}
)
console.log(acc)
```